Nestjs Cron-job using bullmq doesn't work
I implemented cron-job using bullmq in nestjs back-end.
Producer code:
import { Queue } from 'bullmq';
import { BullQueues, BullWorkers } from '../../../../../apps/api-server/src/shared/utils/constants';
import { CronJobDataSource } from '../data-source';
import { PlatformIntegration } from '../../../../../apps/api-server/src/modules/platform-integrations/entities/platform-integration.entity';
import { CalendarPlatforms } from '../../../../../apps/api-server/src/modules/platform-integrations/domain/calendar-platforms.enum';

/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */

require('dotenv').config();

async function getUsersToSyncWithPlatform(platform: CalendarPlatforms) {
  ...
}

export const eventCronJob = async () => {
  console.log('Event Cron Job Called');
  try {
    await CronJobDataSource.initialize();
    // Initialize the BullMQ queue
    const syncQueue = new Queue(BullQueues.SYNC_EVENTS, {
      connection: { host: process.env.REDIS_HOSTNAME, port: Number(process.env.REDIS_PORT) },
    });

    // Function to enqueue jobs
    const enqueueSyncJobs = async (
      platform: CalendarPlatforms,
      users: {
        id: string;
        account: string;
      }[],
      period: number,
    ) => {
      for await (const user of users) {
        await syncQueue.add(
          BullWorkers.SYNC_EVENTS_FOR_PLATFORM,
          {
            platform,
            userId: user.id,
            account: user.account,
          },
          { repeat: { every: period } },
        );
      }
    };

    // Enqueue jobs for Google Calendar
    const usersToSyncGoogle = await getUsersToSyncWithPlatform(CalendarPlatforms.GOOGLE);
    await enqueueSyncJobs(CalendarPlatforms.GOOGLE, usersToSyncGoogle, 20000);

    process.exit();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

Queue event listener Code:
import { Process, Processor } from '@nestjs/bull';
import { Job } from 'bull';

@Processor(BullQueues.SYNC_EVENTS)
export class SyncEventsConsumer {
   constructor() {}

   @Process(BullWorkers.SYNC_EVENTS_FOR_PLATFORM)
   async readOperationJob(job: Job<{ platform: CalendarPlatforms; userId: string; account: string  }>) {
   const {
      data: { platform, userId, account },
    } = job;
    console.log('Cron Job: >>>>>>>>>>>', platform, userId, account);
}

BullModule is connected as Redis in app.module.ts and event listener service is registered as a provider in sub module.ts
But cron-job doesn't work for even one time. I need your help. Thanks.
Producer code is outside of app modules and it's created as a library in nest-cli.json.
When I run nest back-end, I can see that log in producer.
Event Cron Job Called
But I can't see that log in queue event listener. Cron Job: >>>>>>>>>>> ...
I used bullmq module in producer. And I used @nestjs/bull and bull modules in event listner.

I'm not sure why you need to use Bull and BullMQ together, but trying to set up a repeatable job with NestJS and BullMQ, I ended up in your question. After registering the BullMQ connection in the app module and the queue in a separate module, I did the following:
import { InjectQueue, Processor, WorkerHost } from '@nestjs/bullmq';
import { Queue } from 'bullmq';

@Processor('example')
export class ExampleProcessor extends WorkerHost {
  constructor(
    @InjectQueue('example') private exampleQueue: Queue
  ) {
    super();
    this.setupRepeatableJob();
  }

  private setupRepeatableJob() {
    console.log('Setting up repeatable job');
    this.exampleQueue.add('example-job', undefined, {
      repeat: {
        // run it every 10 seconds
        pattern: '*/10 * * * * *',
      },
    });
  }

  async process(): Promise<void> {
    console.log('Processing job');
  }
}


This way, the job processor with its handler. I could run several replicas of my service and see the job is executed every ten seconds by only one replica. I hope it helps.
